# Autocomplete através de java doc no sublime

Tags: php, html, sublime-text-2, ide

Não sei se vou conseguir me expressar corretamente, mas vamos lá.
No Java, quando comentamos o código, utilizamos o padrão

```
/**
* @author Nome do Autor; 
* @method Nome do Método;
*/
```

A partir disso, em uma IDE como o sublime, podemos desfrutar do recurso de auto completar a partir dessas informações. Alguém sabe como configurar ou qual plugin instalar para que esse recurso seja utilizado no sublime text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe um plugin chamado **[DocBlock](https://github.com/spadgos/sublime-jsdocs)** com suporte para PHPDoc.

Ele adiciona automaticamente comentário que comece com `/**` e tem um `*` no início de cada linha. Qualquer linha dentro de um bloco de documentação que não comece com um `*` será ignorada.

```
/** 
 * @author Nome do Autor
 * @method Nome do Método;
 */
function foo ()
{
}
```

Comment: Isso é bacana. Mas quando estiver utilizando o método em outro arquivo, ele vai me oferecer o autocompletar?

Comment: @user3043340, apenas pesquisei este plugin há algum tempo atrás, não tive oportunidade de testá-lo ainda, portanto não tenho experiência prática com o mesmo para lhe responder isto, ainda estou tentando mudar do Netbeans para o sublime :P

Comment: Eu troquei a um tempo, só estou sentindo falta disso. No resto ele é excelente, muito rápido. Vou testar e te digo.